# Javascript regular expression match URL up to a '/'

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to regular expressions and have been trying to match URLs for an app using javascript.

I want to match something like this:

```
/some/url/string/(name)
```

but there are other URLs that use this same string but continue

```
/some/url/string/(name)/some/more
```

and I don't want to match those.

I thought I would need to use `'[^/]'` or `'(?!/)'` to match the (name) field without any following `'/'` but I have not had success with this.

Currently I use this:

```
'/some/url/string/\\S*'
```

But this matches the longer URLs that I don't want to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Code is updated to answer question better, see comments below.

You're so close. You just need to add the `+` quantifier. Your first attempt (using `[^/]`) only went to look for the *single next character*, not multiple characters until the slash.

```
\/some\/url\/string\/[^\/]+$
```

(I added backslashes (`\`) to escape the forward slashes (`/`)).

See working example at [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mM5yS1/3).

Comment: That still matches (part of) the longer URLs OP doesn't want (as shown in your example).

Comment: @PaulRoub No it doesn't. It goes up to the end of "(name)", before the next slash.

Comment: Yes. When, per the question "there are other URLs that use this same string but continue `/some/url/string/(name)/some/more`
and I don't want to match those."

Comment: @PaulRoub Yes, but by that he meant he wanted to match the first part (`/some/url/string/(name)` and not match the `/some/more`.

Comment: We're reading the question differently. Certainly not downvoting over this, since it's a matter of adding a `$` or not...

Comment: @PaulRoub As I was saying, OP said he wanted " to match the (name) field without any following '/'".

Comment: I agree, the question is asking to not match the longer urls, not to match the first portion of the url.

Comment: @PaulRoub is correct, I need to not match these longer URLs at all. I was already able to match the first part of the URL.

Comment: @PeterSamyn, this expression can still work. You just need to add the `$` at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expresion to achieve it, you can try this:
`string.split('/')[4];`

If you are looking for the full path, you can use:
`string.split('/').slice(0,5).join('/');`

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
/some/url/string/[a-z]+
```